# I have to click twice on a jquery button to submit a registeration form

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this page that hides the submit button if the passwords do not match. If they match the button appears but it needs to be clicked twice to submit the form.

**html page**

```
        <form action="registeration.php"  method="post">
          <input style="font-size:15px; text-align: right" type="tel" pattern="[\d\u0660-\u0669]+" placeholder="رقم الجوال ويفضل أن يكون مربوط بالواتس آب" name="Phone" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ضع رقم هاتف جوال هنا!')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/(?![0-9])./gmi,'')" minlength="10" maxlength="10">
          <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" type="text" placeholder="الأسم أو الكنية أو أسم المكتب" maxlength="24" name="User" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('الأسم أو الكنية أو أسم المكتب')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
          <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" type="password" placeholder="كلمة المرور" id="txtNewPassword" maxlength="24" name="Password" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('أدخل الرقم السري هنا')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
          <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" type="password" placeholder="قم بإعادة كتابة كلمة المرور" id="txtConfirmPassword" maxlength="25" onChange="checkPasswordMatch();" name="Repassword" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('أعد إدخال الرقم السري هنا')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
          <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch"> </div>
        </form>
```

**jquery**

```
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var Password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
    var Repassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

    if (Password != Repassword)
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html('<div style="text-align: right" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> !<b>خطأ:</b> الرقم السري غير متطابق </div>');
    else
        $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">قم بإنشاء الحساب</button>');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});
```

**Edit** added snippet

```js
function checkPasswordMatch() {
  var Password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
  var Repassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

  if (Password != Repassword)
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html('<div style="text-align: right" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> !<b>خطأ:</b> الرقم السري غير متطابق </div>');
  else
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">قم بإنشاء الحساب</button>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});

// for testing, don't want to actually submit
$("form").on("submit", function() {
   console.log("submit");
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="registeration.php" method="post">
  <input style="font-size:15px; text-align: right" type="tel" pattern="[\d\u0660-\u0669]+" placeholder="رقم الجوال ويفضل أن يكون مربوط بالواتس آب" name="Phone" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ضع رقم هاتف جوال هنا!')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"
    oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/(?![0-9])./gmi,'')" minlength="10" maxlength="10">
  <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" type="text" placeholder="الأسم أو الكنية أو أسم المكتب" maxlength="24" name="User" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('الأسم أو الكنية أو أسم المكتب')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" type="password" placeholder="كلمة المرور" id="txtNewPassword" maxlength="24" name="Password" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('أدخل الرقم السري هنا')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" 
         type="password" 
         placeholder="قم بإعادة كتابة كلمة المرور" 
         id="txtConfirmPassword" 
         maxlength="25" 
         onChange="checkPasswordMatch();" 
         name="Repassword" 
         required 
         oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('أعد إدخال الرقم السري هنا')"
         onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch"> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @mplungjan can you elaborate more please?

Comment: Where is the button to submit? Also you have lots of events bound to those inputs which is going to cause you inevitable headache

Comment: @maxshuty it's here: `$("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html('<button type="submit" ...`

Comment: @freedomn-m Ups... Totally missed that. I thought the fact that it is used as `keyup` handler is the only place :/

Comment: @Andreas I had to reformat the html in the edit/snippet I added to see it - hate one liner html as it just hides stuff like this

Comment: @AbdulazizAlJumaia Did you actually try my code? It is a lot more elegant.

Comment: @mplungjan I did, but the submit button does not appear after filling the form. I modified the css, html, and js files accordingly.

Comment: Soo the snippet I made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not that you have to click it twice, it's that it's being recreated when you click it, so you're not actually clicking it the first time.

You have both

```
onChange="checkPasswordMatch();"
```

and

```
$("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
```

so when you type the same 2nd password, the button appears, you then immediately "click" on that button, but, as you mouse-down to click the `onChange` fires, deletes your button and creates a new one, which won't register your "click" as it didn't get a mouse-down.

You can confirm this:  type the same 2nd password, then click outside the 2nd input (but not on the button) then click the button and it works ok.

Alternatively, remove the extra `onchange=` and use either antiquated onXX= *or* jquery event handlers, don't mix and match them.

Updated snippet:

```js
function checkPasswordMatch() {
  var Password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
  var Repassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();

  if (Password != Repassword)
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html('<div style="text-align: right" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> !<b>خطأ:</b> الرقم السري غير متطابق </div>');
  else
    $("#divCheckPasswordMatch").html('<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">قم بإنشاء الحساب</button>');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#txtConfirmPassword").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
});

// for testing, don't want to actually submit
$("form").on("submit", function() {
   console.log("submit");
   return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="registeration.php" method="post">
  <input style="font-size:15px; text-align: right" type="tel" pattern="[\d\u0660-\u0669]+" placeholder="رقم الجوال ويفضل أن يكون مربوط بالواتس آب" name="Phone" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ضع رقم هاتف جوال هنا!')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"
    oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/(?![0-9])./gmi,'')" minlength="10" maxlength="10">
  <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" type="text" placeholder="الأسم أو الكنية أو أسم المكتب" maxlength="24" name="User" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('الأسم أو الكنية أو أسم المكتب')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" type="password" placeholder="كلمة المرور" id="txtNewPassword" maxlength="24" name="Password" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('أدخل الرقم السري هنا')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" 
         type="password" 
         placeholder="قم بإعادة كتابة كلمة المرور" 
         id="txtConfirmPassword" 
         maxlength="25" 
         xx_onChange="checkPasswordMatch();" 
         name="Repassword" 
         required 
         oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('أعد إدخال الرقم السري هنا')"
         onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch"> </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just show and hide it?

```js
function checkPasswordMatch() {
  var Password = $("#txtNewPassword").val();
  var Repassword = $("#txtConfirmPassword").val();
  return Password === Repassword;
}

$(function() {
  $("form").on("change", function() {
    const ok = checkPasswordMatch();
    $("[type=submit]").toggle(ok)
    $(".alert").toggle(!ok)
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="registeration.php" method="post">
  <input style="font-size:15px; text-align: right" type="tel" pattern="[\d\u0660-\u0669]+" placeholder="رقم الجوال ويفضل أن يكون مربوط بالواتس آب" name="Phone" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('ضع رقم هاتف جوال هنا!')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"
    oninput="this.value=this.value.replace(/(?![0-9])./gmi,'')" minlength="10" maxlength="10">
  <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" type="text" placeholder="الأسم أو الكنية أو أسم المكتب" maxlength="24" name="User" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('الأسم أو الكنية أو أسم المكتب')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" type="password" placeholder="كلمة المرور" id="txtNewPassword" maxlength="24" name="Password" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('أدخل الرقم السري هنا')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  <input style="font-size:20px; text-align: right" type="password" placeholder="قم بإعادة كتابة كلمة المرور" id="txtConfirmPassword" maxlength="25"  name="Repassword" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('أعد إدخال الرقم السري هنا')"
    onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')">
  <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divCheckPasswordMatch"> </div>
  <div style="text-align: right" class="hide alert alert-danger" role="alert"> !<b>خطأ:</b> الرقم السري غير متطابق </div>
  <button type="submit" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">قم بإنشاء الحساب</button>

</form>
```